# Multiple URL Queries including Text Fields and Dropdown List

Tags: sql, asp.net, url, asp-classic, imacros

I have to **perform a search based on 3 queries in a single URL** and so far i have achieved this

> ...Search.aspx?StartDate=1/9/2015&EndDate=1/9/2015

the third query which i want to include in the above URL is related **to a Drop-Down List containing 100 plus options.**

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CbCM.png)

How should i write the URL to get the required option.

Comment: Does the form with the dropdown do a post or a get?

Comment: I am not sure about that as i am new to it. The dropdown contains a list of 100 plus items and we have to select any one of them to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do something like Search.aspx?StartDate=xx&StopDate=YY&options=selected1,selected2,selected3 ?

Comment: how to write the URL ... considering the following codes for the drop-down

Comment: <label for="Main_Main_ddlLocation" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-12">Location</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <select name="ctl00$ctl00$Main$Main$ddlLocation" id="Main_Main_ddlLocation" class="form-control">
 <option value="0">All Terminals</option>
 <option value="97198">MFK  -387</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="97197">MFK -378 (This Terminal)</option>
 <option value="97200">MFK -384</option>
 <option value="97213">MFK -386</option>

Comment: I assume you have some sort of search button that the user clicks. The button should trigger the form action, in your case the method is probably get. What happens then is that the values of each control within the form should be in the query string. It that is not the case it would be good to see more of the website code.

Comment: u got my point ... i have to search by using a URL query. So considering the above code i wrote this :

Search.aspx?StartDate=1/9/2015&EndDate=6/9/2015&Location=ABCD

but it did not worked.... then i tried 

Search.aspx?StartDate=1/9/2015&EndDate=6/9/2015&Location.option=ABCD

but again it is not working.....

how should i amend my URL query for location options ?

Comment: You might be in trouble using the "/" symbol in the values. I have a feeling you need to encode them or use other symbols in the date declaration.